¿Convertir un print a return cuando está en un loop?
Estoy atascada en un problema porque la funcion debe utilizar un return y devolver un string, pero solo he podido hacerlo con un print. El problema es que es un loop y si pongo un return me va a cortar el loop antes de tiempo.
Es sobre la sucecion de fibonacci, el parametro es la cantidad de numeros que se quieren en la sucecion. Por ejemplo, el resultado de la función, si se pasa como parámetro el número 18, es:
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597 

Tengo esto hasta el momento:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int)->None:
    cuenta=2
    a=0
    b=1
    fin=False
    while fin==False:
        m=(str(a)+","+str(b)) 
        print (m, end=",")
        if cantidad_numeros==cuenta:
            fin=True
        else:
            a=a+b
            cuenta+=1
            b=a+b
            cuenta+=1 

Cumple con el objetivo, pero es obligatorio que utilice return en lugar de print. ¿Ideas?

Lo primero, tu algoritmo es incorrecto, genera un ciclo infinito para cualquier valor de cantidad_numeros que no sea un entero positivo. Esto se debe a dos factores:

Estás agregando dos términos de la serie por ciclo e incrementas cantidad en dos en cada iteración.

Pero tu condición de salida es:
if cantidad_numeros==cuenta:

Como cuenta parte de 2, si incrementas de dos en dos, la condición jamás se cumplirá  si cantidad_numeros es impar (cuenta siempre será par) o negativa (cuenta siempre será positiva).


Por otro lado:

Deberías manejar los casos en los que el usuario ingresa un valor menor de 1.

El condicional interno no aporta realmente nada, usa la condición del while directamente.

La forma pitónica de comprobar si algo es verdadero o falso no es:
if fin == True:
if fin == False:

sino:
if fin:
if not fin:



En cuanto a retornar la cadena ya formada en vez de imprimir, simplemente necesitarás almacenar de alguna forma cada número de la secuencia generado por cada iteración del ciclo. Puedes usar la propia cadena m, pero incrementándola:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int) -> str:
    if cantidad_numeros < 1:
        return ""

    a = 1
    b = 0
    cuenta = 1
    m = "0"
    
    while cuenta < cantidad_numeros:
        m += f", {a}"
        temp = a + b
        b = a
        a = temp
        cuenta += 1
    return m

Ahora bien, cuando se sabe a priori el número de iteraciones, un ciclo for es más apropiado que un while. Esto evita la necesidad de una variable contador, su incremento y el condicional de salida:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int) -> str:
    if cantidad_numeros < 1:
        return ""

    a = 1
    b = 0
    m = "0"
    
    for _ in range(cantidad_numeros - 1):
        m += f", {a}"
        temp = a + b
        b = a
        a = temp

    return m

La concatenación de cadenas es bastante ineficiente, esto se debe a que dada su naturaleza inmutable, cada concatenación requiere crear un nuevo objeto str en memoria. alternativamente, puedes usar una lista como contenedor temporal y luego usar str.join() para construir la cadena final, insertando las comas y espacios entre cada término.
También puedes cambiar:
temp = a + b
b = a
a = temp

por:
a, b = a + b, a

quedando así:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int) -> str:
    a = 0
    b = 1
    m = []
    
    for _ in range(cantidad_numeros):
        m.append(str(a))
        a, b = a + b, a

    return ", ".join(m)

o usar un generador junto a str.join() que evita la necesidad de un contenedor temporal a la vez que genera la cadena de salida en un solo paso:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int) -> str:
    def fibonacci_gen(cantidad_numero):
        a = 0
        b = 1

        for _ in range(cantidad_numeros):
            yield str(a)
            a, b = a + b, a
            
    return ", ".join(fibonacci_gen(cantidad_numeros))


Genial la respuesta, solo una cosita... if fin: no es pitónico. Al menos no en el sentido de ser algo que se haga en python nada más. Con booleans eso se hace en cualquier lenguaje si no me equivoco (en java lo usamos un montón) y en TypeScript (y si te gusta javascript también...) se hace con cualquier valor también gracias a los falsy/truthy. Es decir, un if evalúa si una condición es TRUE o FALSE, pasarle directamente un booleano siempre es correcto y evita comprobaciones redundantes en cualquier lenguaje :)

@Benito-B si tienes razón, lo de "pitónico" lo decía más por el lado de la legibilidad del código,, de hecho aparece explícitamente en PEP-8. Python permite también la conversión implícita a bool (a través del método __bool__ de cualquier objeto), por lo que por ejemplo se puede hacer if cadena:  o if lista: para comprobar si un str/list no están vacíos, o if num: para ver que un entero no es cero (aunque aquí no se aplica la coerción como tal, bool deriva de int).

Desde el punto de vista de la eficiencia, concretamente en Python, usar if objeto == True frente a if objeto: en estos casos, se traduce en 3-4 instrucciones más de bytecode dependiendo del tipo del objeto en cuestión...

Realmente con un return no lo vas a lograr pero si con un yield que es una especie de return. Para ello debes hacer un pequeño cambio:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int)->None:
    cuenta=2
    a=0
    b=1
    fin=False
    while fin==False:
        m=(str(a)+","+str(b)) 
        yield m
        if cantidad_numeros==cuenta:
            fin=True
        else:
            a=a+b
            cuenta+=1
            b=a+b
            cuenta+=1 


Entonces haces lo siguiente:
for n in sucesion_fibonacci(18):
   print(n,end=",")


El "yield" convierte a la función en un generador por lo tanto puedes utilizarlo en un for. El valor de "n" va a ir tomando lo que la función le devuelva con yield.

Puedes ir acumulando los resultados en una variable, para hacer return de esta al final.
La variable puede ser una cadena o una lista. Sin cambiar la lógica de tu solución, quedaría algo como:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int)->str:
    cuenta=2
    a=0
    b=1
    fin=False
    result='';
    while fin==False:
        m=(str(a)+","+str(b))
        result+=','+m if result!='' else m 
        if cantidad_numeros==cuenta:
            fin=True
            return(result)
        else:
            a=a+b
            cuenta+=1
            b=a+b
            cuenta+=1 
            
print(sucesion_fibonacci(10))

que produce la salida:
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34

Hay varios cambios adicionales que se pueden hacer, el más obvio es que en realidad lo que hace que se rompa el ciclo es el return, por lo que no haría falta la variable de control y podría quedar simplemente while True.
Con una lista, quedaría algo como:
def sucesion_fibonacci(cantidad_numeros: int)->list:
    cuenta=2
    a=0
    b=1
    result=[];
    while True:
        result.append(a)
        result.append(b)
        if cantidad_numeros==cuenta:
            return(result)
        else:
            a=a+b
            cuenta+=1
            b=a+b
            cuenta+=1 
            
print(sucesion_fibonacci(10))

que produce la salida:
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]

Finalmente, si se llama a la función con un número impar, va a entrar en un bucle infinito, en cualquiera de los casos, pues se evalúa la igualdad exacta. Corregir ese bug queda fuera del alcance de la respuesta, queda en tí encontrar una solución para ello.

@aeportugal estoy al tanto de eso y es justo lo que he dicho en el último párrafo de mi respuesta, añadido unos 5 minutos después de publicarla, pero unos 15 antes de tu comentario.

Tienes razón, no vi eso en el párrafo. Asumo que por no corregir ese problema te pusieron el downvote (no fui yo).
